# Linking libraries in Windows

Tags: python, c, gcc, dll, cython

I'm having troubles finding information on how to link libraries simply in Windows.

Linux seems to have these lovely gcc options (from [here](http://technozeal.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/writing-and-compiling-c-program-using-custom-library/))

```
gcc MadgwickAHRS.c -o MadgwickAHRS
```

Whereas I have to use something like this in Windows (from [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL)):

```
gcc -c -DBUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL  MadgwickAHRS.c
gcc -shared -o MadgwickAHRS.dll MadgwickAHRS.o -l,--out-implib,MadgwickAHRS.a
```

The first one gives me this error:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

And the second one, this error:

> gcc.exe: MadgwickAHRS.a: No such file or directory

(I have no idea how I was supposed to make a `.a` file from the instructions given). I've never been able to properly link libraries and I've been using `#include "file.c"` (that has a `#include "file.h"`) instead of the `#include "file.h"` just because it worked. But I'd like to learn the "proper" way to do it, and seeing as how my Cython code seems to be overwriting my .c code... I figured it was time to try something else.

If you want to help me with my Cython/numpy problems/tell me it will never work I'll attach that too. My code isn't too well commented/written yet so there's that... But it should show the most basic idea of what I'm trying to do with my new linked library/shared object thing.

I can't seem to figure out a good way to paste the code so I'll just include it from pastebin. This is mostly Madgwick's work taken from his website (the link is the code).

Here are the pastebin "links":

[MadgwickAHRS.c](http://pastebin.com/bvxR6rWC)

[MadgwickAHRS.h](http://pastebin.com/ir54PA6k)

[MadgwickAHRS.pyx](http://pastebin.com/Ba35napB)

[MadgwickAHRS.pxd](http://pastebin.com/GUMPHz7m)

[setup.py](http://pastebin.com/VqzA8Ve9)

GCC version 4.5.2

Windows 7

Python 2.6

Edit:

I tried

```
gcc -shared MadgwickAHRS.c -o MadgwickAHRS.o
```

got my MadgwickAHRS.o, wrote a quick main.c

```
#include "MadgwickAHRS.h"
int main (void) {
    MadgwickAHRSupdate(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    return 0;
}
```

then ran this

```
gcc -c main.c  -o main.o
```

and then linked them

```
gcc main.o MadgwickAHRS.o -lm -o main
```

got my exe and ran it with no errors. Is there anything else I should know before moving on? Thank you for the replies. :)

Edit:
I eventually got linking to work thanks to your comments.
I used

```
gcc -shared MadgwickAHRS.c -o MadgwickAHRS.o
```

Comment: Try the fist command without `-c` but with `-shared`. Anyld maybe specify the outfile.

Comment: Also, try to write the build command in a single line to see if that works first, then break it down to multiple steps. Btw, which version of MinGW is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify that you're building console application. It seems that you compile as window applcation. Try to find out how to change project's type. WinMain - is entry function for windows application. 
May be this flag will help you *--subsystem,console*

Comment: I'm actually just trying to wrap the c function into python.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Niklas R

```
gcc -shared MadgwickAHRS.c -o MadgwickAHRS.o
```

creates the .o file I needed